# Why can't I send SendGrid email from Lambda Function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sendgrid

I'm struggling to understand why my Lambda won't send this Sendgrid message.

When I invoke the Lambda, I get console.log 1,2,3 in that order as well as null from the Sendgrid invocation. The Sendgrid promise callbacks are never invoked. Any idea why?

```
"use strict";

const sendgrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');

sendgrid.setApiKey('xxxxxxxxx');

module.exports.scan = async (event, context, onComplete) => {
  console.log('1');

  await (() => {
    console.log('2');
    sendgrid.send({
      to: 'xxxxxxx',
      from: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
      text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
      html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('cool');
      onComplete(null, "successfully updated form next_scheduled")
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error');

      //Log friendly error
      console.error(error.toString());

      //Extract error msg
      const {message, code, response} = error;

      //Extract response msg
      const {headers, body} = response;

      onComplete(error, "failed to updated form next_scheduled")
    });
  })();

  console.log('3');
};
```

Comment: Have you checked your sendgrid SendGrid UI/dashboard at https://app.sendgrid.com/ to see if anything shows up there? Nothing jumps out at me as wrong with your code, though I would lint it if you haven't, just in case.

Comment: I recreated your code with a simple async method in place of the send() call and it works as expected. The code right now is a little hard to read with the mix of async/await, promise chains, and immediate functions. I would suggest defining the async function as a real function and refactoring everything to async/await and try/catch to make it easier to debug

Comment: Thanks for the input, the code I've provided is a simplified version of the production code. I think it may be a communication issue actually. The Lambda is inside a VPC

Comment: I concur with @bwest.  You can't... or at the very least, you *shouldn't*... mix an async function with the Lambda callback (which you have named `onComplete`).  Communication issues do not explain **none** of the sendgrid callbacks firing -- you should catch an error.  But I this async function is returning, and not returning a promise, and at that point Lambda is likely calling things "done."

Comment: @ShaneDaSilva Were you able to find a solution to this? I am facing similar issue where my sendgrid client is able to send mail when running locally but not working on AWS Lambda. It simply gets stuck on sgMail.Send() part.